# Identifying Repeat values in a column - Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Is there a way in spotfire to identify repeating values in a column based on different dates?

Suppose there are columns: `Date`, `Store number`, `Result`

We see that store numbers 27, 35 are repeated in different dates and it should display in result column as Y. But if store numbers are repeated in a same date it should not be taken into account.

```
+------------+----------+-----------------------------+
|    Date    | Store No | Result in Calculated Column |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------+
| 05/14/2015 |       23 |                             |
| 05/14/2015 |       27 | Y                           |
| 05/14/2015 |       23 |                             |
| 05/14/2015 |       35 | Y                           |
| 05/14/2015 |        2 |                             |
| 05/14/2015 |       27 | Y                           |
| 05/15/2015 |       31 |                             |
| 05/15/2015 |      101 |                             |
| 05/15/2015 |       88 |                             |
| 05/15/2015 |       31 |                             |
| 05/15/2015 |       27 | Y                           |
| 05/15/2015 |       35 | Y                           |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: @Solomon- This sentence contradicts output shown in your table. 'But if store numbers are repeated in a same date it should not be taken into account.' Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `INTERSECT()` with an `OVER` clause.

```
If(Count([Store No]) over (Intersect([Store No],All([Date])))<>Count([Store No]) over (Intersect([Store No],[Date])),"Y")
```

This is basically saying if the count of the store number for the date of the current row doesn't equal the count of the store number across all dates, then place a Y.